# Why doesn't my Entity Framework code first DbContext show the entities from my populated table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to deploy my app to a testing environment, but cannot get Entity Framework to play nicely with the database. In development, I use a database initializer to seed the database and that has worked flawlessly. However, when I deploy the application to an actual IIS instance I cannot get it to interface with the database. My custom initialization rules aren't run at all, so I am instead creating the database manually.

I used the ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript() as a starting point for my SQL script, and SSMS verifies that two rows are populated in the appropriate table.

My problem arises after running the application. I have custom membership and role providers, neither of which seem to detect that the two roles exist in the database.

How do I get my entity framework to recognize that these rows aren't empty? I'm currently using a private DbContext inside a repository to handle communication with Entity Framework, and disabled my custom initializer until this hiccup is resolved.

Code that attempts to find roles in the database:

```
context.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == role)
```

The database shows the following in the Roles table:

```
Id  Name     Description
1   Company  NULL
2   Customer NULL
```

The LINQ generates an empty sequence exception, as context.Roles is empty.

Comment: might seem like a obvious point, but have you set explicitly set the connection string for the applicationservices in your web.config?? on the local dev machine, all would have been fine due to the convention over configuration aspect of the sqlserver express db getting used as per the dbcontext name etc.

Comment: @jimtollan A connection string is specified.

Comment: ok - that helps narrow it down.. will get back in a bit. what do you get if you query:`context.Roles.All()` (or whatever your wrapper requires for All()) -oops, just saw that you mentioned context.Roles is empty!! - ignore my comment

Comment: do any queries to the database work?  Or is the problem just with the Roles?

Comment: @kevinsky The only table with entries right now is Roles. I'm just trying to get a smoke test of sorts to pass to figure out how to deploy an EF code first application.

Comment: Seeing as this is smoke test why not verify basic connectivity with a direct query?  something like var data =  db.Database.SqlQuery("select count(*) from roles");

Comment: @kevinsky db.Database.Exists() returns true. However, db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select count(*) from Roles") returns -1 from the application, whereas it returns 2 from an external script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I went through to migrate from a code first project with a custom IDatabaseInitializer implementation that reset the database during each session to a non-volatile DB setup.

First, copy the schema generated by Entity Framework in your dev. project by running the following code and placing the output in an accessible location (ie: file on desktop, raw text in browser, etc). **context** is an instance of your class that inherits from **DbContext**:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript()
```

Second, save the string returned from that call in a SQL file. Be sure to remove the command that creates the Entity Framework meta data table. This command should resemble the following:

```
create table [dbo].[EdmMetadata] 
( 
    [Id] [int] not null identity, 
    [ModelHash] [nvarchar](max) null, 
    primary key ([Id]) 
);
```

Next, remove the code that seeds the database. I used an AppSetting so that I can easily toggle that code's usage after deployment without needing to re-compile and deploy.

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mode"] == "Dev")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<PonosContext>(new PonosInitializer());
    new MyContext().Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Immediately outside of that statement, you still need to intialize the database, but make sure to pass in **false** so that the initializing will only happen if the database has not been initialized.

```
new MyContext().Database.Initialize(false);
```

Finally, run your setup SQL on an empty database to have the tables created with appropriate fields.

If you deploy and then run your application, it should connect to the database and be able to work as normal with any data you loaded in an external script. I tested this method successfully with custom membership and role providers.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments it looks like there is no connection between Entity Framework and the database. You don't mention which version of Entity Framework you are using but I assume you have updated to the latest (4.3 as of time of writing).

I notice you say that you are "creating the database manually.".  Why not open a test project and create a new database first model based on your manually created database?  This should at least confirm that you can use Entity Framework with your configuration. 
From there I would create another project from scratch to test the Code First approach.

Comment: I setup a new application that uses the database first approach with my manually created database. The roles are correctly retrieved from the database. However, the code first approach in the application concerning this question does not retrieve the roles successfully.